# Proving the area of an equilateral triangle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

How do you prove that How do you prove that for any equilateral triangle with side length s, area is $\frac{s^2 √3}{4}$ ? I tried using an equilateral triangle in a square, but I keep coming up with a $2x^2√3$ , as shown below. What am I doing wrong?

I started with the following:
[image: Imgur]

The area of the full square is:
$ 2x * 2x = 4x^2$

To find the area of the triangle, I will subtract the non-triangle parts from the square.

The part shaded green is:
$ (2x - x√3) * 2x = 4 x^2-2x^2√3$

The parts shaded blue are:
$ \frac{x   *   ( x√3)}{2} + \frac{x   *   ( x√3)}{2} = x^2√3$

Adding blue and green:
$(x^2√3) + (4 x^2-2x^2√3) = 4 x^2-x^2√3 $

Subtract blue and green from whole square:
$(4x^2) -(4 x^2-x^2√3) = x^2√3$

Multiply by 2 because I am referring to the $2x$ side, not half of it ($x$):

Final answer: $2 * (x^2√3) = 2x^2√3$

And of course, $ 2x^2√3 \neq \frac{x^2 √3}{4}$

Comment: Since the triangle doesn't fit in a square, don't use a square. Instead use a rectangle with height $x\sqrt3$ and width $2x$. Then the top vertex of the triangle lies on the top edge of the rectangle, and is exactly half  the area of the rectangle, which is is $2\sqrt3\cdot x^2$ as you said. Notice that you have made $x$ be *half* the side length $s$, so the rectangle is  $2\sqrt3 x^2$ = $2\sqrt 3 \frac{s^2}4$ and the triangle is half of this.

Comment: You have doubled one side, so when it comes to areas, everything is scaled up by a factor of 4. To get your answer, you need to divide by 4! Your calculations are correct until your derivation of $x^2\sqrt{3}$. Instead of doubling it, quarter it.

Answer (score 1):

As I was saying in my comment, your choosing of a side equal to $2x$ scales everything up by a factor of $4$, therefore you need to divide by $4$, not double at the end.

Here's your original figure scaled so that the side equals $x$. Notice that if you do your calculations again, you'll end up with the correct area: $\dfrac{x^2\sqrt{3}}{4}$.

[image: Area of equilateral triangle]

Comment: What is the length of EH and area of EDGH in terms of $x$?

Comment: I've marked $DG=EH=x(1-\sqrt{3}/2)$ in the figure.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a rectangle wit height $x\sqrt{3}$ and length $x$ such that the right angled triangle with legs as the sides forms half of the equilateral triangle (as shown in the picture in the question). Then, the area of the right angled triangle is $\dfrac{1}{2}x^2\sqrt{3}$. Two times this is the area of the equilateral triangle. This gives $x^2\sqrt{3}$. Now, $x$ is half of the side $s$ of the equilateral triangle, i.e., $x=s/2$, implying that the area is $\dfrac{s^2}{4}\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using calculus. For instance, consider the line $f(x) = \sqrt{3}x $. Notice the line from $(0,0)$ to $(\frac{s}{2}, f( \frac{s}{2}) ) $ is the hypothenuse of half the equilateral triangle. The other sides are $\frac{s}{3}$ and $\sqrt{3} \frac{s}{2} $. So, the area of half of the equilateral triangle is

$$ \int\limits_0^{\frac{s}{2}} \sqrt{3} x = \frac{ \sqrt{3} s^2}{8}$$

And hence the area of the equilateral triangle is twice this area which is

$$ \frac{ \sqrt{3} s^2}{4}$$