# Area of an equilateral triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, area

> Prove that if triangle $\triangle RST$ is equilateral, then the area of $\triangle RST$ is $\sqrt{\frac34}$ times the square of the length of a side.

**My thoughts:**

Let $s$ be the length of $RT$. Then $\frac s2$ is half the length of $\overline{RT}$. Construct the altitude from the $S$ to side $\overline{RT}$. Call the intersection point $P$. Now, you have a right triangle whose sides are $|\overline{RP}| = \frac s2$ and $|\overline{RS}| = s$. By the Pythagorean Theorem, $|\overline{SP}| = \sqrt{s^2 - \frac14 s^2} = \sqrt{ \frac34 s^2} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} s$. The area of the triangle is $$\frac12 \left(|\overline{SP}|\right)\left(|\overline{RT}|\right) = \left(\frac12 s\right) \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} s\right) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}s^2,$$ as suggested.

Comment: Hello.  Sorry that you immediately received multiple downvotes and close votes without anyone bothering to tell you what you can do to improve.  The reason you've been downvoted and voted towards closure is that you haven't really shared your thoughts on the problem at hand, or where you are having difficulty.  I urge you to edit the question ASAP adding your ideas before the question is closed.

Comment: What I can think is the triangle is divide into two, become isosceles triangle.

Comment: I thought the previous comment you made was your attempt at the solution.  Was I wrong?  I edited it into your question.

Comment: Good move, now you have shown exactly how to prove this statement. (Notice the typo in the statement.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving the area of an equilateral triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766640/proving-the-area-of-an-equilateral-triangle)

Answer (score 0):

Let the lenght of the side be $s.$

In an equilateral triangle, the lengths of the sides are equal.

So, $RS=ST=TR=s.$

All angles are $\frac{π}{3}$ $radians.$

Area of a triangle as we know, is $$\frac{(RS)(ST)\sin(S)}{2}.$$

$$=\frac{s^2\sin(\frac{π}{3})}{2}$$

The area of the $ΔRST$ is thus,  $$\frac{s^2\sqrt3}{4}$$

$Quod  $   $erat $   $demonstrandum$

Comment: Besides, your thoughts are perfect.

Answer (score 0):

From [AoPS wiki](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Area_of_an_equilateral_triangle),

> Method 1: Dropping the altitude of our triangle splits it into two triangles. By HL congruence, these are congruent, so the "short side" is $\frac{s}{2}$. Using the Pythagorean theorem, we get $s^{2}=h^{2}+\frac{s^{2}}{4}$, where $h$ is the height of the triangle. Solving, $h=\frac{s \sqrt{3}}{2}$. (note we could use $30-60-90$ right triangles.)
> We use the formula for the area of a triangle, $\frac{1}{2} b h$ (note that $s$ is the length of a base), so the area is
> $$
> \frac{1}{2}(s)\left(\frac{s \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)=\frac{s^{2} \sqrt{3}}{4}
> $$
> Method 2: (warning: uses trig.) The area of a triangle is $\frac{a b \sin C}{2}$. Plugging in $a=b=s$ and $C=\frac{\pi}{3}$ (the angle at each vertex, in radians), we get the area to be $\frac{s^{2} \sin c}{2}=\frac{s^{2} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{2}=\frac{s^{2} \sqrt{3}}{4}$